# Load remote data from an AngularJS directive

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I come from a background of jQuery, but I'm attempting to learn AngularJS with a weather web app I'm building.  I have 4 select boxes at the top of the page with a list of cities.  Each select box corresponds to a weather container below that displays the current weather for that selected city.

I'm using a directive for the weather containers as shown below.  Is this the proper way to structure this?

```
<weather city="select1"></weather>
<weather city="select2"></weather>
<weather city="select3"></weather>
<weather city="select4"></weather>
```

When I select ATL from select box #1 it shows ATL in the weather container for select1.  That part works.  But now I need it to go out to the server and get the weather data that will be displayed in that directive.  I have an API working that I can pass ATL to and it returns the weather data as JSON.  What's the proper angular way of doing this?  I couldn't find in directives where to call my services, like ui-router has `resolve`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('yourApp')
    .directive('weather', ['$http', function ($http) {
        template: '<div data-ng-click="getWeather()">{{weatherData}}</div>',
        scope: {
            city: '='
        },
        controller: function(scope) {
            scope.getWeather = function() {
                $http.get('/your-weather-api?city=' + scope.city)
                    .success(function(data) {
                        scope.weatherData = data;
                    });
            }
        }
    }]);
```

Something like that would probably work, but I don't think that's the best way to structure your project. Can you post your code or preferably a plnkr, we might be able to help more with that?

Here is a plnkr showing a rough approach that may be a bit easier to manage than what you're after:
http://plnkr.co/edit/XcjkfOpuiaasGWa3C0Lv?p=preview